# what is the purpose of having duplicate styles in css?

Tags: html, css, web

i have seen some people in css write something like

```
.together
 {
display:inline;
display:inline-block;
 }
```

not just restricted to display style, but say background-size or background-image for an example

what is the purpose of this? i mean the second one is going to override the first one, so why bother?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a possibility that it's written that way for browser-compatibility. They probably want the element to have a `display` value of `inline-block`, but not all browsers support it on all elements. Sitepoint has a good reference for compatibility of the [display property](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display).

The [`background`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background) property is a shorthand for all of the background-related properties, so it's common to set `background` on one selector and then only overwrite specific background properties later on other selectors. And again, you might have multiple background declarations for browser compatibility.

Comment: and if a browser takes both values? this means order also matters?

Comment: Yes, order matters.  The last value applied that is valid is the one that is used.

Comment: Yep, a browser that understands both will use the last one. It should behave the same as if the two property declarations were in sequential selector groups.

Answer (score 7):

Usually this type of behavior indicates a browser hack for compatibility.  When browsers detect a property or value they do not know, they ignore it.  Thus, if you place the most widely-accepted properties first, browsers will "fall back" to that behavior if none of the latter properties are compatible.

Answer (score -2):

Lets take the following example.

```
<html> 
<head>      
<style>
.carlist
{
    background-color: red;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body  onload="loadCars()">

Check div style.
<div  id="mydiv" class="carlist"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above example we have 2 margins declared. I checked and found that the **2nd declaration** is accepted by browser(FF,IE,Chrome).  So **I think if we use this for browser compatibility then the most browser specific style should be declared at last.** But there are other ways to define browser specific styles. So its better to have single attribute defined.

Comment: Both `margin` properties are the same; this example wouldn't help with browser compatibility.

Comment: My focus was not on browser compatibility. My intention was to tell that browser takes the latest declaration when duplicate declaration is there.

Comment: Ok.  That was unclear to me in my first read through this answer.